# Fading styling in a jquery menu script

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

See I have downloaded this code from somewhere in the WEB. But I don't remember. Anyway, I want to add fading effect to menu on mouse overing on of menu headers. The current script is as follows---

Jquery Code----

```
            var timeout         = 500;
            var closetimer      = 0;
            var ddmenuitem      = 0;

            function menu_open()
            {   menu_canceltimer();
                menu_close();
                ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).css('visibility', 'visible');}

            function menu_close()
            { if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

            function menu_timer()
            {   closetimer = window.setTimeout(menu_close, timeout);}

            function menu_canceltimer()
            {   if(closetimer)
                {   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
                    closetimer = null;}}

            $(document).ready(function()
            {   $('#menu > li').bind('mouseover', menu_open);
                $('#menu > li').bind('mouseout',  menu_timer);});

            document.onclick = menu_close;
```

Html Code -----

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="menu_head"><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">jQuery Plugin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ajax Navigation</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li  class="menu_head"><a href="#">Effect</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Slide Effect</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fade Effect</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Opacity Mode</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Shadow</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Semitransparent</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu_head"><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
<li class="menu_head"><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
<li class="menu_head"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried just adding `FadeIn()` and `FadeOut()` effect but it did not worked. Please help me out with.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7cEbk/
I think this is what you want.

-michael

```
        var timeout         = 500;
        var closetimer      = 0;
        var ddmenuitem      = 0;

        function menu_open()
        {   menu_canceltimer();
            menu_close();
            ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).hide().fadeIn();}

        function menu_close()
        { if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.show().fadeOut('fast');}

        function menu_timer()
        {   closetimer = window.setTimeout(menu_close, timeout);}

        function menu_canceltimer()
        {   if(closetimer)
            {   window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
                closetimer = null;}}

        $(document).ready(function()
        {   $('#menu > li').bind('mouseover', menu_open);
            $('#menu > li').bind('mouseout',  menu_timer);
        });

        document.onclick = menu_close;
```

Comment: But the thing is when i mouseover the contents of the menu it disappears! Please help me with this...

Comment: There are a couple problems, and the reason I changed up the code some in my latest jsFiddle (http://www.jsfiddle.net/HUWPB/3). First, you are specifying ddmenuitem as the UL element to show/hide. But since you are using a timer to fade them out, that value still contains an old element in it while the timer expires and you are mousing over a new item (repopulating that variable with the new UL). Second, you are specifying menu_close() in your menu_open() function. This causes some odd behavior because of the first point.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there, I was just messing around with this in jsFiddle... I think the problem was that you were calling menu_close() in your menu_open() function. This was causing havoc with fadeIn() and fadeOut().

This probably won't be your final solution, but it might get you going in the right direction. I broke apart the chaining for clarity, feel free to reconnect it.

```
function menu_open() {
    menu_canceltimer();
    ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0);
    ddmenuitem.fadeIn('slow');
}

function menu_close() {
    if(ddmenuitem) {
        ddmenuitem.fadeOut('slow');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working. No fade and no sign of menu to appear.

Comment: Strange... I posted the code I was using here on jsFiddle. Check it out, click the run button and you'll see the HTML on the right. It's not perfect, but it is fading in/out.  http://jsfiddle.net/HUWPB/1/

Comment: I updated my jsFiddle to use the jQuery hover function instead of binding to mouseover/mouseout. The updated sample isn't using a timer to close the menu, but is closing immediately. But, the code may help some. Here's the updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/HUWPB/3/ -- Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Modifed JS

```
var timeout = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function menu_open() {
    menu_canceltimer();
    menu_close();
    ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).fadeIn('slow');
}

function menu_close()
{ if (ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.fadeOut('slow'); }

function menu_timer()
{ closetimer = window.setTimeout(menu_close, timeout); }

function menu_canceltimer() {
    if (closetimer) {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu > li').bind('mouseover', menu_open);
    $('#menu > li').bind('mouseout', menu_timer);
});

document.onclick = menu_close;
```

Comment: Wow! It still does not work. I wonder what's getting wrong no sign menu to appear or fade! But Thanks for some advice!